# Adding a create comment page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Rails beginner here. I'm having trouble with commenting on posts. I have the comments working when they are on the same page as the post but after trying to set up seperate pages for creating and viewing the comments i get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments", :id=>"27"} missing required            
keys: [:post_id]
```

My posts/show.html.erb file: (the second line is the link that's causing the problem)

```
<h class="eventhead"><%= @post.description %></h>

<%= link_to "Add comment", new_post_comment_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-medium" %>
```

And here's my comments/_form.html.erb file:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<p>

<%= f.input :title, :subtitle, :body, :label => "New Comment", as: :text, input_html: {        
rows: "3" } %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a nested resource, so this requires that you pass in the post_id to the `link_to`.  Revise your code as:

```
<%= link_to "Add comment", new_post_comment_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary btn-medium" %>
```

Just as @jaycode mentioned you will need to make sure the `comment#new` action assigns `@post`in your controller.

```
# comments_controller.rb

def new
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.:) Any chance you know how to change my index method in my comments controller to only show the comments from one post? Here it is:                                                   def index
 @comments = Comment.all
end

Comment: You should find the post using something like `@post = Post.find params[:post_id]` and then after finding the post you can just call `@post.comments` to only show comments that belong to that post.  This assumes you have the correct `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship set up.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Rails :)

Check the content of method new_post_comment_path. Most likely it requires :post_id variable to be passed into it.

Perhaps you should use this instead:

> 

And make sure in comments_controller.rb action new (**def new** in that file), you have @post_id variable defined.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! For some reason it's not displaying your code.